# Will Android Emulator automatically run with hardware acceleration if KVM is installed and Use Host GPU was selected at the time of AVD creation?

Tags: android, linux, emulation, kvm

Android Emulator can be run using `qemu/kvm` on a Linux box as following.

```
emulator -avd Nexus5 -qemu -m 2048 -enable-kvm
```

If I have kvm installed and working on my system and I choose `Use Host GPU` while creating an AVD when I run the emulator will it be already running with hardware acceleration support through kvm?

Secondly, how do I make sure if the `avd` is running under `kvm` or is being hardware accelerated?